# ReferenceError: DashboardComponent is not defined

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm getting this error when learning from [Angular2](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html) tutorials. I have checked everything but not found the error. Here is my code below

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/router-deprecated';
import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes.component';
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';


@Component({
    selector:"my-app",
    template:`
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <nav>           
            <a [routerLink]="['Heroes']">Heroes</a>         
        </nav>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers:[
        ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
        HeroService
    ]
})

@RouteConfig([                      
        {
            path: '/dashboard',
            name: 'Dashboard',
            component:DashboardComponent,
            useAsDefault:true
        },
        {
            path:'/heroes',
            name:'Heroes',
            component:HeroesComponent
        }
])

export class AppComponent { 
    title = "My Heroes App";
}
```

**dasboard.component.ts**
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-home',
    template: '<h3>My Dashboard</h3>'
})
export class DashboardComponent {}
```

Everything is working perfect when I remove following code block from `@RouteConfig`

```
{
    path: '/dashboard',
    name: 'Dashboard',
    component:DashboardComponent,
    useAsDefault:true
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import the `DashboardComponent` component as well:

```
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';
```

I only see the `HeroesComponent` one imported...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error message with the "Tour of Heroes" tutorial. The tutorial says

`Also import and add DashboardComponent to our root NgModule's declarations.`

OK, I know how to import a component:

`import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';`

but where does it need to be imported to? The above answer says to import it into `app.component.ts`. IMHO that's incorrect. The only module that is imported into `app.component.ts` is

`import { Component } from '@angular/core';`

Instead, `DashboardComponent` needs to be imported into two files: `app.module.ts` and `app.routing.ts`.